# How to select a range of dates in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that I want to extract certain date ranges to look at the differences monthly/seasonally in R. The data has a column of date values.

Q: How to obtain the full rows of the dataset within a date range I specify?

Comment: This question is better suited for SO and would benefit from a short example of how your data looks like (especially what the date format is).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `Date` class: if you are using a `data.frame`:

```
myData[myData$myDate >= "1970-01-01" & myData$myDate <= "2016-06-27",]
```

And if you are using a `data.table`:

```
myData[myDate >= "1970-01-01" & myDate <= "2016-06-27"]
```

Comment: The first one was what I was looking for, thank you and apologies for the off topic.